# Reference website for CSS 3 properties (like box-reflect)

Tags: web-development, css

Today, I started reading the book *CSS Mastery 2nd edition*. It is really a good book for anyone who is interested in learning some techniques. On page 151, I discovered the `box-reflect` property from CSS3. I tried to find out more information about which browser suports it and the syntax of the property, but I only found a site that didn't explain much.

Can anyone please provide me with a link to a website that is up to date regarding the CSS3 elements? The site should also contain information about browser-support for the different elements. I'm primarily interested in the `box-reflect` property and to update my knowledge of CSS3 properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definitive source, really, is http://www.w3.org/Style/CSS/. However, this doesn't include vendor-specific implementations.

For vendor-specific implementations, check out http://peter.sh/experiments/vendor-prefixed-css-property-overview/.

Answer (score 1):

Like Demian said, the best source is the official [W3 CSS](http://www.w3.org/Style/CSS/) page.

Here you can find [compatibility issues](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html).

And here's an [online editor](http://css3please.com/) to automatically write cross browser css rules.